# modifying object inside useEffect() doesn't update the state

Tags: promise, axios

I am new to React and the use of Hooks. I am trying to fetch an object from some API, transform it (based on result from yet another API) and update the state inside the useEffect hook. However, the object transformation is not reflected when the DOM gets rendered. Here is my code.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let modified_movies = []
    axios.get(LOCAL_MOVIE_API)
      .then(res => {
        const movies = res.data.content;
        movies.map(async movie => {
          const response = await axios.get(_API,
            {
              params: {
                query: movieTitle,
                year: movie.movieYear
              }
            });
            const poster = response.poster; //add property to object
            const modified_movie = { ...movie, poster_url: poster };
            modified_movies.push(modified_movie)
        })
        setMovies(modified_movies) //
      })
  }, [])
```

I am not modifying the object in-place either and therefor making a copy of the object, however react still doesn't update the state with modified object and the new property is not reflected in the view. Am I missing something obvious or is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with react.

Your `movies.map(async movie => {...` call, is creating `Promise`s, which will execute after your `setMovies` call, so the `modified_movies` array will be empty. So you need to wait until the `map` function is done, and then set the state.

One way of solving the issue:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let modified_movies = []
    axios.get(LOCAL_MOVIE_API)
      .then(res => {
        const movies = res.data.content;
        const moviePromises = movies.map(async movie => await axios.get(_API,
            {
              params: {
                query: movieTitle,
                year: movie.movieYear
              }
            })
        ) // map all the calls into one array 
        Promise.all(moviePromises).then((allResponses) => {
            // allResponses will be an array of values, which you can map to your needs
            setMovies(allResponses) //
        })
      })
  }, [])
```

Here's some useful documentation:

[Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

[Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with React or useEffect.

You're just having a problem with Promise.

Consider this example:

```js
// ----------- YOUR   WAY --------------
const getRandomValue = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(Math.random());
    }, 10);
  });
};

const movies = [1, 2, 3];

const modified_movies = [];

movies.map(async(movie) => {
  modified_movies.push(await getRandomValue());
});

console.log("modified movies with map", modified_movies);

// ---------- One of correct ways -----------------

const Movies = [1, 2, 3];

const modifiedMovies = [];

const getModifiedMovies = async() => {
  for (let movie in movies) {
    modifiedMovies.push(await getRandomValue());
  }

};

getModifiedMovies().then(() => {
  console.log("modified movies with for let", modifiedMovies);
});
```

The first approach simulates your way, which always return an empty array.

The second approach awaits all promises to be resolved, thus return the correct one.

So back to your problem, I think the code should be like the following:

```js
axios.get(LOCAL_MOVIE_API)
  .then(async(res) => {
    const movies = res.data.content;
    for (const movie of movies) {
      const response = await axios.get(_API, {
        params: {
          query: movieTitle,
          year: movie.movieYear
        }
      });
      const poster = response.poster; //add property to object
      const modified_movie = { ...movie,
        poster_url: poster
      };
      modified_movies.push(modified_movie);
    }
    setMovies(modified_movies);
  });
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to provide on which state change useEffect should be triggered, something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
      // your logic here
      })
  }, [theStateWhichChanged])
```

Comment: useEffect is already getting triggered for the first time so that is not a problem in my case.

Comment: @Sajjad in that case you need to wait for promise to complete, a .then after await block might help, use setState logic inside then block.

Answer (score -2):

Your dependency array is empty, that means that the code inside the useEffect is executed when the component mounts and ONLY at this one time.
To me, the code looks overly complicated and has missing parts (where does movieTitle, movie.movieYear come from?). I suggest you split your requests in to functions inside the useEffect to make it more clear for yourself.

If you have a state the effect depends on (e.g. another state), then you need to add i to your dependency array:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  // your code here
}, [movies])
```